# return instance of the class on dynamic library

Tags: c#

I learn, how dynamic load dll to program. I have test class on library:

```
public class Class1
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string GetWorld()
    {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

In my program code dynamic load this library and function TestLibraryMethod return instance of Class from library. So how it's write correct?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var DLL = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\TestLibrary.dll");
            var reportType = DLL.GetTypes().ToList().Where(t => t.Name == "Class1").Single();
            var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(reportType);
            Class1 test=(call TestLibraryMethod()?)
            Console.WriteLine(test.Number);  
            Console.WriteLine(test.GetWorld());                              
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }

    public static Class1 TestLibraryMethod()
    {
        Class1 test = new Class1();
        test.Number = 5;
        return test;
    }
}
```

Comment: What you have to think about is how the program can know about the assembly at compile time when you only reference it at runtime.

Comment: I understand it, that this not possible. In this situation I ask in this topic how it would be better?

Comment: I'm wondering why you are doing this. The main reason I can think of to dynamically load assemblies like this is for things like plugins and in that case I'd expect you to have an interface that they are required to implement that you could then use to refer to that type. Perhaps you should explain a bit more about what you are tryign to achieve here?

Comment: I have library from another programmer . I write program, which dynamic load dll, when another programmer check-in this is dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the type is not known at the compilation stage of your process, you need to use reflection to access it. You can find an [introduction to that topic on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3a58006.aspx).

For example, taking your example, to read the property and invoke the method you would write this:

```
PropertyInfo NumberProp = reportType.GetProperty("Number");
Console.WriteLine(NumberProp.GetValue(instance));

MethodInfo GetWorldMethod = reportType.GetMethod("GetWorld");
Console.WriteLine(GetWorldMethod.Invoke(instance, null));
```

It's not a great deal of fun using reflection in this way. I rather suspect that you would be better off defining an interface in an assembly used by both your host assembly, and the dynamically loaded assembly. In the dynamically loaded assembly you would define a class that implements the type and provide a method that creates and returns a new instance. In that way you can bind to the type at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

What @David was referring to is, you can't normally do this. However, if you still want such a functionality, you need to think interfaces (or contracts) to get this done.

Say in assembly A, you have the interface defined:

```
public interface IRunnable
{
   void Run();
}
```

In assembly B you have the concrete implementation. So this assembly references A. Therefore a class in assembly implements IRunnable.

In your front-end, i.e. the target assembly (it may be a desktop app, or a web app, or any app), you add reference to assembly A. Assembly B is dynamically loaded. And that particular type is instanced like you've done above, and the instance is give to an IRunnable variable.

So in your case, the instancing code will be:

```
var instance = (IRunnable) Activator.CreateInstance(reportType);
instance.Run();
```

This is the recommended way to do so.